# Turn array into HTML table, with empty cells for missing values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with numeric values. Each value is different, and the array is sorted ascending, from min 1 to max 80.

```php
$numbers = array( "1", "3", "5", "6", "12", "13", "15", "20",
                  "24", "28", "32", "33", "34", "42", "47",
                  "49", "50", "54", "59", "79");
```

I want to show this array in one table row, each number in a cell, with non-present values showing as empty cells, like this:

```html
<tr>
    <td>1<td>
    <td><td>
    <td>3<td>
    <td><td>
    <td>5<td>
    <td>6<td>
    ....
```

In other words, if the value is missing from the array, an empty table cell should be inserted instead. In the above example, the cells where `2` and `4` would go are empty, because those values are not in the array.

In total, there will be 80 `<td>`.

Comment: I suppose you could loop from 1 to the max value in the array and output a `<td>` cell each iteration of the loop.  When outputting the cell, check if the array contains that value.  If it does, output the value as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is solved the problem like this:

```
$numbers=array("1","6","7","10","12","16","17","22","27","34","35","45","49","52","53","56","57","76","78","80");

function results($array){
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i=1; $i<81 ; $i++) { 
        if (in_array($i, $array)) {
            echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

results($numbers);
```

Comment: You should accept the @cale_b answer... also that code is cleaner than what you've posted here (you have two different places that can generate the table cell markup, for instance, instead of just one). (IMO)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use your code. Is more clean and easy to understand

Answer (score 6):

What about something like this (assuming min of 1 and max of 80):

```
echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 80; $i++) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo ( in_array( $i, $numbers ) ) ? $i : '';
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

If you wanted to dynamically find the min / max of the array:

```
$min = min( $numbers );
$max = max( $numbers );

echo '<tr>';
for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo ( in_array( $i, $numbers ) ) ? $i : '';
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```